# How can I make a matrix same as MNIST image dataset.

Tags: c++, opencv, mnist

I'm trying to make a vector matrix, which is the same as MNIST image dataset. 
Each image from the webcam is captured and store into the vector. However the matrix i created is different from the MNIST dataset. So the main code doesn't work for matrix I created.

I was thinking that maybe its because the pixel type is different.
What I noticed is, when I looked up a single matrix from MNIST data it had 15 decimal points. However I was not able to set 15 decimal points. When I set the image to be CV_FC64. It shows following error message. 
"Assertion failed  in cv::cvtColor, file C:\file path. "

The main code works for MNIST dataset.. I'm not sure what to do..

please advice. me.

```
 while (1)
    { 
        cap >> src;

        src.convertTo(src, CV_64FC1);
        src = src / 256;

        cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        resize(src_gray, src_N, size);
        testX.push_back(src_N);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvtColor` only allows `8U`, `16U` and `32F` bit-depths. So after you `convertTo(..., CV_64FC1)`, the bit-depth is `64F` and the assertion fails: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/84699e0e1860a3485e3dfc12230fbded955dba13/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L8676:

```
     CV_Assert( depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F );
```

If you really need 64F, it'd make sense to first `cvtColor` and then increase bit-depth to 64F using `convertTo`.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution!